# I'm new in android studio & java , Lack of knowledge & logic to do Calculator. Need helps

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm thinking how to do when I click the button first time it will show the result. After that i click the second time then the button will clear the result.

**Example**: First time Click, It will Calculate

```
R.id.Equal: calculate(true);
```

**Calculate's Method**

```
private void calculate(boolean IsEqualClick) {
        String input = getinput();
        try {
            if (!isEmpty()) {
                if (input.contains("x")) {
                    input.replaceAll("x", "*");
                }
            }
            Expression expression = new ExpressionBuilder(input).build();
            double result = expression.evaluate();
            if (IsEqualClick) {
                inputtext.setText(String.valueOf(twoDForm.format(result)));
                resulttext.setText("");

            } else {
                resulttext.setText(String.valueOf(twoDForm.format(result)));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            stateError = true;
            isNumber = false;
        }
    }
```

I can't think of how to write a code If i Click second time, it will delete. should I use the if statement again to progress it?

Comment: Why would you want click on `=` button to clear result, and not calculate anything? Makes not sense to user.

Comment: what do you mean by `IsEqualClick`? better `switch` with `.setTag()` & `.getTag()` - or by key-codes, when using a keyboard... the input is always either numerical or operator input.

Comment: Just like android's calculator. after showing the answer you click the number second time. the first result will all clear @Andreas

Comment: IsEqualClick is a boolean to check the answer.  I wanted to do is Button A + Button B = Ans. After showing the Ans, I click Button A again. It will delete the previous Ans and start with a new for the users. @MartinZeitler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to check that `isEqualClick` if you have properly written the switch statement plus it is hardcoded so there is no meaning behind it.

Now for your solution do something like this:-

Declare a global variable `boolean toCalculate = true;`, this variable will check if we have to calculate or we have to clear the box;

Function call for `calculate();`

```
R.id.Equal: calculate();
```

The `calculate()` function:-

```
    private void calculate() {
              if (toCalculate) {
                     String input = getinput();
            try {
                if (!isEmpty()) {
                    if (input.contains("x")) {
                        input.replaceAll("x", "*");
                    }
                }

                Expression expression = new ExpressionBuilder(input).build();
                double result = expression.evaluate();
                /*->Write all your code for printing the answer here<-*/
                /*for eg:- result.setText(String.valueOf(twoDForm.format(result)))*/ 
                toCalculate = false;
              } catch (Exception e) {
                 stateError = true;
                 isNumber = false;
                }
                } else {
                 /*->Write all your code for clearing the answer here<-*/
                 /*for eg:- result.setText("")*/    
                 toCalculate = true;
                }

        }
```

Or you can do something like this and you don't have to change the function like we did above:-

```
 R.id.Equal: if(toCalculate)
              {
                 calculate();
                 toCalculate = false;
              }else
              {
                 /*->Write all your code for clearing the answer here<-*/
                 /*for eg:- result.setText("")*/
                 toCalculate = true; 
              }
         break;
```